# Google Calendar gone nuts since DST has ended

Tags: nexus-4, google-calendar, google

Ever since the 28th of October when DST has ended all of my events in my Google Calendar has moved one hour earlier. The web calendar shows currect dates and times but the one on my Nexus 4 is one hour early.

I tried using 'Home time' in the calendar settings without success.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting `Automatic date & time` and `Automatic time zone`?

[image]

**Source:** [Daylight Saving Time and Android: Sit back and relax](http://www.androidcentral.com/daylight-saving-time-and-android-sit-back-and-relax)

Answer (score 0):

Check your calendar settings and see if you're using Home time zone. I've got mine using home time zone and it has no problems switching between DST.

Calendar -> Settings -> General settings

[image]